# affine and linear application how to recognize?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know what linear applications are,  but now thatt I am studying affine application my professor asked me to recognize if some functions were linear , affine or both . These are the questions

1)$\ f: K_{≤n}[T] \to K_{≤n}[T] $ such that $\ f(p(T)) = p(T + 1)$

I said that this can't be linear because zero is not mapped into zero but it is affine , because exist $\ b \in  K_{≤n}[T] $ such that $ p(T + 1)-b $ is linear

2)$\ I: C([a, b], R) \to C_1([a, b], R)$ such that  $\ I(f)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$

I said it is linear so it is also affine

3)$\ det : M(3; K) \to K$ such that  $A \to det(A)$

It is not linear and also not affine

are my answers correct?

Comment: Even if obvious to some people, I’m not sure I understand your notation. What is K, T, p?

Comment: @Ralff Hi thanks for answering with p i mean polynomials , T variable , K ring of polynomial . Do you think my consideration are ok ?